# import error when trying to import express-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt

Here is the error I'm getting. Please help.

> C:\Users\Val\Desktop\merncamp\server\middleware\index.js:1 import
> expressJwt from "express-jwt";
>
> SyntaxError: The requested module
> 'file:///C:/Users/Val/Desktop/merncamp/server/node_modules/express-jwt/dist/index.js'
> does not provide an export named 'default'
>    at Object. (C:\Users\Val\Desktop\merncamp\server\middleware\index.js:1)
>    at Generator.next ()
>    at Object. (C:\Users\Val\Desktop\merncamp\server\routes\auth.js:1)
>    at Generator.next ()
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)

Comment: Google might help: Import Error Does not provide export named default

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write a title that describes the problem. The first part of your title is totally redundant, as almost everyone who asks a question is seeking for help and the second part seems to describe the broader task but not the specific problem. Please also read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact context of what you are trying to do, I will however take a shot in the dark.

The error you are seeing implies that you are asking for something that doesn't exist, based on the way you are trying to import express-jwt.

When code modules in javascript are created they can have named exports and a default export.

From your error it looks like you are importing using the following statement

`import expressJWT from 'express-jwt'`

This is asking for the 'default' export from that module. Looking at the NPM page for the package it looks like `expressJWT` is a named export. If this is the case, you would need to modify your import statement to the following

`import { expressJWT } from 'express-jwt'`

I hope this helps. For next time, try adding your code that is causing the error to help others to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt";
const requireSignin =expressjwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});

export default requireSignin;

or

var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");

const requireSignin =jwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});

export default requireSignin;
```